# how to call python script from spring-cloud-stream based micro-service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am thinking of using spring-cloud-stream to building message-driven micro-service application using RabbitMQ as the broker.

I see that spring-cloud-stream is built on top of Spring-Integration(SI) and SI provides spring-integration-scripting to execute python scripts. But I don't know how to hook this up in spring-cloud-stream.

So what I want to know is when a message arrives on a queue, how can I execute a python script in turn and get the output of the script?

Any code and config example would be helpful.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks
GM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose Spring Cloud Stream provides particular `Processor` [Application](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/processor/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-scriptable-transform).

You can just register it into your Spring Cloud Data Flow and configure it with desired script.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't want to transform the payload. What I want is when I receive a message on a channel I want to run some business logic as part of the logic is to also run the script and grab the output and then store the output in to DB or put it back on another channel. Any code sample would be good.

Comment: It is just called `transformer`, but the target script logic is fully depends on you. So, that processor responsibility is to call an external script (Python ?) and send the result into the `output` channel. I don't understand your concern...